# i cant access my files in media file system in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, user-permissions

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkp3s.jpg) cant access the directories in media file system on my mobile via my Ubuntu 14.04 
can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restart the ubuntu system and your phone. Try it again.
Which connection mode your phone is in? MTP or USB mass storage?
Check your cable. And are you able to connect and use other USB devices on this system? Are you able to use this phone to do transfers on other computer?

Comment: there's a connection with the mass storage but all directories are read only

Comment: and only i wanna change the permission of the accessing the files in my mobile

Comment: Can you try on Windows machine? If directories are read only, it might have to do with the way ubuntu mounts the file system on your phone. You might have better luck posting this question on askubuntu.com.